# Core Data, executeFetchRequest return 1 object, haven't saved anything

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode5, nsfetchrequest

When I call fetchQuery method in my table view controller it returned an object with null properties, but I haven't saved anything yet. In fact, I have just cleaned up my xcode cache and IOS simulator. Here are my fetchQuery method:

**In My viewDidLoad**

```
NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

**In my viewWillAppear**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
self.people = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];
[self.table reloadData];
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
Person *temp = ((Person*)[people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
PersonCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"personCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PersonCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"personCell"];
}

[cell setPersonDetails:temp];    // just assigning label value, had double checked, it works.
return cell;
```

This strange behaviour ruins the numberOfRowsInSection count by the extra count that leads to the following exception in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10)
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Screenshot Explanation:

- Date: DOB
- Number: Row count
- Blank area between date and number: should be NSString firstName

[image]

Comment: Could you post the output of the console log?

Comment: Is there a reason why the people array is mutable?

Comment: can you put more snippet ,for idea?

Comment: try like this 
 NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [newDevice valueForKey:@"MyattributeName1"], [newDevice valueForKey:@"MyattributeName2"]]])

Comment: @FelixLam: The reason is because user will be able to add person onto people and I called [self.table reload] method which is to reload the table cells.

Comment: Why not just use an NSFetchedResultsController? This is what it is designed for.

Comment: @DhavalBhadania I tried to put more in there, but the remaining is only UITableViewCell initialization.

Comment: @Abizern could you please explain the different between NSFetchedResultsController and normal NSFetchRequest? And why would I used NSFetchedResultsController instead of common NSFetchRequest? (I am used to NSFetchRequest, that's the only reason I am using it).

Comment: NSFetchRequest pulls data out of a persistent store into a managed object context. NSFetchedResultsController is designed to efficiently managed the request and provide the data for a UITableViewController. As an aside, adding objects to an array is the wrong approach. To add objects - add the to the managed object context and let the NSFetchedResults controller manage the changes.

Comment: @Abizern thanks for the tips, I will implement it tomorrow and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you should use a NSFetchedResultsController. The best way to learn about it is to look at Apple's template: create a new project, choose "Master/Detail" and check "Core Data".

In the master view controller you will see an implementation of a lazy-loading fetched results controller, as well as all the delegate callbacks (this will update your table view automatically if the database changes).

As for your stray object - it was most probably created somewhere, maybe during initiation of your database. However, you should check your other table view datasource methods. If e.g. these return a `count` of one row per section, your cell implementation could result in this empty `Person` object.

One way to check what has actually been stored is to fire up the `sqlite3` command line tool and examine the sqlite file in the documents directory.